# Laravel 8 add GET parameters to return view from controller

Tags: laravel-8

I'm realy new with Laravel :)

In a laravel 8 controller there is a way to add an additional GET parameter to a view return?

In web.php I've:

```
Route::get('/listtestmodel', 'TestmodelController@list')->name('listtestmodel');
```

I've in the controller (in list function):

```
 return view('page.list', ['list' => $list]);
```

$list is a variable with a model collection to be rendered in view.

I want to add to the page url a new parameter.
Now I've

**/listtestmodel**

I need something like

**/listtestmodel?par=345**

Comment: Welcome to SO ... then what ever you are using to generate the URL to that route add that extra parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to add parameters to the query string when generating the url you can simply do that:

```
// This will output the url with the query string
route('listtestmodel', ['par' => 345]);
```

Then in your controller you can get the parameter via the request helper

```
request()->input('par');
```

Alternatively, if you are ok with having a url **/listtestmodel/345** you can change your route and get the parameter this way:

```
// Route in web.php
Route::get('/listtestmodel/{par}', 'TestmodelController@list')->name('listtestmodel');


// Method in controller
public function list($par)
{
...
}
```

If your parameter is a model ID, you should use the second approach and use Route Model Binding provided by Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding