# How to add additional parameter when sign in with Microsoft OAuth using Laravel League/oAuth

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory, calendar, laravel-8

I have a Laravel application which will sync doctor appointment in Microsoft Calendar.

**Laravel package used:**

1. `"league/oauth2-client": "^2.6",`
2. `"microsoft/microsoft-graph": "^1.49"`

Now, my situation is doctor is signed in `https://tenant.project.dev` and he needs to use microsoft consent screen(oAuth) to allow our application to sync patient appointment to his microsoft calendar.

Now redirect url is saved in Azure portal as `https://project.dev`.

What I want is when microsoft redirects to that redirect url it will add additional parameters with like `tenant_id=1&doctor_id=2&referrer_url=https://tenant.project.dev` or parameter with encrypted request so, that I can decrypt it later in my redirect route.

Example:

```
https://project.dev?code=xxxxx&state=xxxx&params=xxxxxx
```

Can it be possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you can redirect the route using  one of the following ways in references.

For example ,if route points something like below

```
Route::get('/signin', 'AuthController@signin')
```

Try to return the redirect in that specific controller something like below:

```
public function signin()
  {
return redirect()->action('UsersController@index',['id' => 10,‘&params’=>123]);
or 
//return redirect()->action('AdminController@index', ['id' => $id) ->with('message', 'Status message');

}
```

Please check the references which can be worked around in your case .

**References:**

1. [Build PHP apps with Microsoft Graph - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=3)
2. [Laravel 8 add GET parameters to return view from controller - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753876/laravel-8-add-get-parameters-to-return-view-from-controller)
3. [Laravel Passport - Laravel - The PHP Framework For Web Artisans](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#requesting-tokens-redirecting-for-authorization)
4. [redirect route with parameters laravel Code Example (codegrepper.com)](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/redirect+route+with+parameters+laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution for this problem.

Need to use an array parameter when trying to get authorization url using `getAuthorizationUrl` method. Like below:

```php
<?php

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;

$oauthClient = new GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => config('azure.appId'),
    'clientSecret'            => config('azure.appSecret'),
    'redirectUri'             => config('azure.redirectUri'),
    'urlAuthorize'            => config('azure.authority') . config('azure.authorizeEndpoint'),
    'urlAccessToken'          => config('azure.authority') . config('azure.tokenEndpoint'),
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    'scopes'                  => config('azure.scopes')
]);

$authUrl = $oauthClient->getAuthorizationUrl([
    'state' => Helper::CustomEncode(json_encode(
        [
            "referrer" => $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],
            "param1" => "new value",
            "param2" => "another value",
            "param3" => "even another value",
        ]
    ))
]);

// Redirect to AAD signin page
return redirect()->away($authUrl);
```